# RxJS Debounce with priority

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm having trouble coming up with this stream.

What I'm looking for is something like `debounceTime` but with priority.

So if I have events with the shape `{ type: 'a', priority: 2 }`. These events needs to be debounced by a few seconds but instead of the last event being emitted, the event with the highest priority is emitted.

```
input stream:
------(a|1)--(b|3)---(c|2)-----------------------(a|1)-----------------


output stream:
-----------------------------------(b|3)---------------------(a|1)-----
```

I've try looking at other operators like `window` and filtering through the result for the last event but it's not ideal because `window` work on a fixed cadence where I want the timer to start on the first event like debouncing does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll offer the following solution, based around using `scan` to offer up the highest given priority emission so far for consideration by `debounceTime()`.  Note that scan needs to reconsider new data after every successful debounce, so I use the operator `window()` to split up the emissions, starting a new observable window after every emission by `debounceTime()`.

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/rxjs-so-57632656-xd1wk)

And here is some simplified code from the CodeSandbox showing the important bits:

```
const resetScan$ = new Subject();

source$.pipe(
  window(resetScan$),
  mergeMap(win$ => win$.pipe(
    scan((acc, cur) => acc.priority >= cur.priority ? acc : cur )
  )),
  debounceTime(debounceDelay),
  tap(() => resetScan$.next())
);
```

Comment: All the submitted solutions work but this one I find the most elegant. I was thinking `scan` would be be a good way to keep the one with the highest priority and you showed this nicely. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 3):

You have to store and update the item with the highest priority and map to this `highest` value which you then pass to `debounceTime`.

```js
let highest = null;
source$.pipe(
  map(v => highest = highest && highest.priority > v.priority ? highest : v),
  debounceTime(2000),
  tap(() => highest = null)
);
```

You can create your own operator that does this with the help of `defer`. `defer` makes sure that every subscriber gets its own `highest` variable, as every subscriber will get its own new Observable created by calling the given factory function.

```js
function debounceTimeHighest<T>(dueTime: number, getHighest: (curr: T, high: T) => T): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => defer(() => {
    let highest: T = null;
    return source.pipe(
      map(item => highest = highest ? getHighest(item, highest) : item),
      debounceTime(dueTime),
      tap(() => highest = null)
    );
  });
}

// Usage
source$.pipe(
  debounceTimeHighest(2000, (v1, v2) => v1.priority >= v2.priority ? v1 : v2)
)
```

The code above is Typescript. If you want plain Javascript just remove all the types.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hitqxk

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the debounceTime and buffer and filter operator to achieve what you need. I have developed this small example for it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lwzt4k

```
/*
Collect clicks that occur, after 250ms emit array of clicks
*/
clicks$.pipe(
  buffer(clicks$.pipe(debounceTime(1000))),
  // if array is greater than 1, double click occured
  map((clickArray) => {
    document.querySelector('#emittedObjects').innerHTML = (`<div>${JSON.stringify(clickArray)}</div>`); 
    const sortedArray = clickArray.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.priority < b.priority ? 1 : -1;
    });

    const output = sortedArray.length > 0 ? sortedArray[0] : null;
    document.querySelector('#mappedOutput').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
    return output;
  })
)
.subscribe((obj) => {
  const str = obj ? JSON.stringify(obj) : 'NULL';
  document.querySelector('#throttledOutput').innerHTML = `<div>THROTTLED: ${str}</div>`;
});
```